# How to find out product id from "woocommerce_cart_item_removed" hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'after_remove_product_from_cart' );
function after_remove_product_from_cart($removed_cart_item_key, $instance) {
    $product_id = $removed_cart_item_key['product_id'];
}
```

I want to find out a way to get product id or actual product object itself using $removed_cart_item_key. How do you do it? I cannot find any references, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

should be something like this...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'after_remove_product_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function after_remove_product_from_cart($removed_cart_item_key, $cart) {
    $line_item = $cart->removed_cart_contents[ $removed_cart_item_key ];
    $product_id = $line_item[ 'product_id' ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, newbie questions: What are 10 and 2 for?

Comment: I had to use the 'woocommerce_cart_item_removed_title' hook. Just a BTWs. In doing so, all I had to do to retrieve the item I was looking for was `$cart['some property']`, because $cart only gave the item that was deleted...

Answer (score 3):

Because it happen before the cart item is removed, you need to use `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` instead of `woocommerce_cart_item_removed`, to retrieve this product item.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 'after_remove_product_from_cart', 10, 2 );
function after_remove_product_from_cart($removed_cart_item_key, $cart) {
    $product_id = $cart->cart_contents[ $removed_cart_item_key ]['product_id'];
}
```

See [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385655/adding-a-hook-to-remove-item-in-a-woocommerce-cart) from [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking)

Comment: I can actually use this solution for my own problem, which is similar to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to fetch the product id of item removed from cart, It worked for me

$product_id = $cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['product_id'];