# WooCommerce cart: Get the cart item Key ID of a specific removed item

Tags: php, templates, session, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce, I have a custom `cart.php` template, where I need to check if a product (item) removed is particularly one of a kind and then based further coding on that information.

Is there a way to find this ONE Key id of a removed item without using hooks, namely the one from the notice `'“Item X” removed. Undo?'`?

I can't find any solution anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean "without using hooks" ? Hooks are specifically made for this. You can also use js hooks if you want that approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760650/how-to-find-out-product-id-from-woocommerce-cart-item-removed-hook

Answer (score 1):

You can get removed cart items in two ways:

- From the WC_Cart object using:

  ```
  $removed_items = WC()->cart->get_removed_cart_contents();
  ```
- From WC_Session object using:

  ```
  $removed_items = WC()->session->get('removed_cart_contents');
  ```

To target a specific removed product and get its Key ID *(and the Undo URL or the remove URL from it)*, use:

```php
$targeted_product_id = 25; // Set the product ID to target
$targeted_item_key   = ''; // Initializing

// Get removed cart items
$removed_items = WC()->cart->get_removed_cart_contents();

// Loop through removed cart items
foreach( $removed_items as $item_key => $item ) {
    $product_id   = $item['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

    if( in_array($targeted_product_id, [$product_id, $variation_id]) ) {
        $targeted_item_key = $item_key; 
        break;
    }
}
// get the Undo URL
$undo_url = WC()->cart->get_undo_url( $targeted_item_key );

// Test output Undo URL
echo '<a href="'. $undo_url .'">'. __("Undo Url") . '</a>';

// get the remove URL
$remove_url = WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $targeted_item_key );

// Test output remove URL
echo '<a href="'. $remove_url .'">'. __("Remove Url") . '</a>';
```

Comment: To make story clearer: I add a product programmatically on cart.php by default. If user removes it, I don't want to force the product (it's a paid membership) on this user again. That's why I need to check if this membership was removed from the cart.

When I use `cart contents`, either `->cart` or `->session` this outputs all the products removed in current wp session (?). If user removes membership, then adds it back and again removes this will crush the idea of using `cart contents`. So I was looking for a way to intercept ID from notice `item removed, undo?`

Thanks for the effort!